# Why doesn't work INSERT and UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this. Im scanning a directory with files (ex.:count.php.2013-04-11_151028.bak ). From file name i need only date and time and i want to insert them in a database - table (table2) with 2 fields (file_date -timestamp , count-int). Count verify how many times a date is in that folder (for example: if 5 files name contain some date count will be 5. If date from file no have records in db the date will be inserted and count will be 1.). All inserted files will be removed from source directory to another because i dont want to scan all times the same files.

$dir = "route1";
$files = scandir($dir);

```
foreach ($files as $file_name)
{
$data = '';
$an = substr($file_name, -21, 4);
$luna = substr($file_name, -16, 2);
$zi = substr($file_name, -13, 2);
$ora = substr($file_name, -10, 2);
$min = substr($file_name, -8, 2);
$data = $an. '-' .$luna. '-' .$zi. ' ' .$ora. ':' .$min.':'.'00';

if(strtotime($data) == FALSE )  continue;

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT count(*) as total FROM table2 WHERE file_date='$data'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if($row >0) {
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE table2 SET count=count+1 WHERE file_date='$data'");
        }
else    {
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO table2 (file_date, count) VALUES ('$data',1)");

$source = "route1";
$destination = "route2";

foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (in_array($file, array(".",".."))) continue;

    if (copy($source.$file, $destination.$file)) {
     $delete[] = $source.$file;
            }
            }
foreach ($delete as $file) {
        unlink($file);
            }   
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`count()` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). You'll need to put it in ticks:

```
UPDATE table2 SET `count`=`count`+1 WHERE file_date='$data'
INSERT INTO table2 (file_date, `count`) VALUES ('$data',1)
```

Comment: The table from database still empty. The update i think is working, but insert no if the table is empty. Because i put manually a date from 1 file with count 1 and after refresh count is 2.

Comment: [No, COUNT is not a reserved word in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html). Still, it is a bad idea to use COUNT as a field name.

Answer (score 1):

well i found the problem and is this : 
replace line:
      if($row >0)

with:
      if($row ['total'] >0).

And the problem is done! Insert and Update work. Thanks!